# Void between delegates not working - Objective-C Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, delegates

ECHOAppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)charlieInputTextHandler:(NSString *)theMessage {

    if (jarvisSecondTimeCheck1 == TRUE) {


    NSRunAlertPanel(@"ECHO", theMessage, @"", @"", @"");

    NSData *sendData1 = [theMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[inputPipe1 fileHandleForWriting] writeData:sendData1];
    NSData *sendReturn1 = [@"\r" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[inputPipe1 fileHandleForWriting] writeData:sendReturn1];
    [ContentsTextField1 insertText:theMessage];
    [ContentsTextField1 insertText:@"\r"];


    } else {
            NSRunAlertPanel(@"ECHO", @"The task is not running; therefore, you cannot send DATA to JARVIS.", @"", @"", @"");
    }

}
```

ChatController.m:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{

    ECHOAppDelegate *echo = [[ECHOAppDelegate alloc] init];

    [echo charlieInputTextHandler:[message stringValue]];

    if(![jid isEqual:[message from]]) return;


    if([message isChatMessageWithBody])
    {
        NSString *messageStr = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];

        NSString *paragraph = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n", messageStr];

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *mps = [[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
        [mps setAlignment:NSLeftTextAlignment];

        NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
        [attributes setObject:mps forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
        [attributes setObject:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:250 green:250 blue:250 alpha:1] forKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];

        NSAttributedString *as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:paragraph attributes:attributes];
        [as autorelease];

        [[messageView textStorage] appendAttributedString:as];

    }
}
```

Ok, for some reason jarvisSecondTimeCheck1 (a bool global variable) returns FALSE even though that I know 900% that it's true because I clarified that in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

And the other part of the code:

```
NSData *sendData1 = [theMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[inputPipe1 fileHandleForWriting] writeData:sendData1];
NSData *sendReturn1 = [@"\r" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[inputPipe1 fileHandleForWriting] writeData:sendReturn1];
[ContentsTextField1 insertText:theMessage];
[ContentsTextField1 insertText:@"\r"];
```

Does not work either. But again, I know this works. Is it because I'm triggering charlieInputTextHandler from another delegate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a hell of a lot of relevant code.  At a rough guess, I'd say this is a big clue as to what's going wrong:

> ```
> ECHOAppDelegate *echo = [[ECHOAppDelegate alloc] init];
> ```

You shouldn't ever need to instantiate your app delegate more than once.  I'd expect something like the following instead:

```
ECHOAppDelegate *echo = (ECHOAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

I'm assuming you're setting `jarvisSecondTimeCheck1` on your original instance and expecting it to be set on any other instance you instantiate.  This isn't how objects work.  I strongly recommend reading [the iOS Application Programming Guide section on the app delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW32) and [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594).

Comment: It's a mac app. Would I change it to NSApplication?

Comment: Yes, if it's a Mac app, use `NSapplication`.

Comment: If your problem is `jarvisSecondTimeCheck1` not being set, then you should post the code where you are trying to set it.

Comment: Hmm..now it's not even running charlieInputTextHandler. Ideas?

Comment: Oh, I know that jarvisSecondTimeCheck1 is being sent, because another part of my code that runs checks for jarvisSecondTimeCheck1 being TRUE and that runs fine. So it's JUST that little snippit of code that's being tricky.

Comment: Have you actually set your app delegate to be the app delegate anywhere?  What does `NSLog(@"%@", echo)` give?

Comment: 2011-05-28 11:36:17.667 ECHO[15187:a0f] <NSWindow: 0x11d562d10>

Comment: That's saying that you've assigned an instance of `NSWindow` to be your app delegate.  This doesn't sound right.  Are you getting compiler warnings?

Comment: ld: warning: directory '/Users/elijahwood/Desktop/JARVISNEW/ECHO-new/../JARVISNEW/ECHO' following -L not found

Yes, this. But I don't think this has anything to do with it.

Comment: Would that be an interface builder problem, should I reassign the delegate?

Comment: Use `NSLog` at the point you assign the value to.  If the memory locations don't match, you've got two different instances of your app delegate, so somewhere you are wrongly instantiating your app delegate.

Comment: 2011-05-28 11:55:41.782 ECHO[26606:a0f] <ECHOAppDelegate: 0x11d939fa0>
 THIS is what I get using my code. That I posted.

Comment: INTERESTING: 2011-05-28 11:57:36.728 ECHO[27566:a0f] (null)

Comment: THIS is what I get when I try to get the value of jarvisSecondTimeCheck1. It's not seeing it?

Comment: Okay, they don't match.  So what I said applies - look for the places you instantiate and assign your app delegate.

Comment: I'm very confused... I can't find ANYTHING.

Comment: On Mac OS, you reach the application delegate by using `[NSApp delegate]`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of your pointers is nil.  Sending a message to a nil object will give you nil,  which could explain why you're not seeing the results you expect.  So check all your pointers and `IBOutlet` variables to ensure they are set correctly.  And check any assumptions too!